# Thinktecture IdentityServer how do I redirect after sign out?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, wif

In my Relying party application (ASP.NET MVC4), I have a Sign Out link which logs me out of IdentityServer. I'm landing on it's "Successful Logout" page with a link back to my app. What I want to do is click the link, "logout" of IdentityServer, and land only my local view "LoggedOut". How can I accomplish this? I'm sure this is common but I can't find any coding examples. Thanks so much for any help. here is my logout code...

```
public class LogoutHandler
{
    public string Signout()
    {
        FederationConfiguration cfg = FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration;
        var fam = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
        fam.SignOut(false);
        var signOutRequestMessage = new SignOutRequestMessage(new Uri(fam.Issuer), fam.Realm);

        return signOutRequestMessage.WriteQueryString();
    }
}
```

Then in a controller action,

```
public ActionResult Logout()
{
string signoutUrl = new LogoutHandler().Signout();
return new RedirectResult(signoutUrl);
}
```

This simply signs me out but I land on the IdentityServer successful sign out.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you simply need to specify the redirect URL in the thinktecture administration zone.  Furthermore, you have to make sure your logout page is not secured.  Without this last part, you come back to the logout page but are immediately redirected back to the STS.